# Is it possible to retrieve the xpath by which an webelement was found?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Let's say I have an Web Element called *we* found by using `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr"))` and I pass the `we` to a method. In the mean tine my `we` is going through something(that sends me StaleElementReference) and i need to retrieve it again in the method i passed it through, to get a child from it. 

Can I somehow get the `xpath` i initially found it by? Please try to answer the question in this context. Thanks

Comment: There is no native way. Since the "finding" logic within WebDriver is all abstracted in a `By` class (or it's equivalent in your language), then it's easier to accomplish. You'll just need to create a wrapper class that holds the `By` reference that was used.

Comment: @Arran make it an answer so i can chose it